# Textbox not active (responsive)

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to write a code of a c++ project that consists of a main window and a child window that works as a properties window that is used to enter some information for the some engine .I tried to add a textbox "Edit" window_style but the textbox is not responsive unless the child window style is without title bar .What is wrong here?

````
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WNDProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);
LRESULT CALLBACK ChWNDProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);

int main()
{
    
    WNDCLASSEXW m_wc = { 0 };
    m_wc.lpszClassName = L"MianWindowClass";
    m_wc.lpfnWndProc = WNDProc;
    m_wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    m_wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    m_wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDC_ICON);
    m_wc.hIconSm = m_wc.hIcon;
    m_wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassExW(&m_wc);
    

    WNDCLASSEXW c_wc = { 0 };
    c_wc.lpszClassName = L"ChildWindowClass";
    c_wc.lpfnWndProc = ChWNDProc;
    c_wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    c_wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    c_wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, IDC_ICON);
    c_wc.hIconSm = c_wc.hIcon;
    c_wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClassExW(&c_wc);

    HWND mw_hwnd = CreateWindowExW(NULL, L"MianWindowClass", L"Main Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 800, 600, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (!mw_hwnd) { cout << "Creation of Main Window Failed" << endl; return -1; }

    HWND cw_hwnd = CreateWindowExW(NULL, L"ChildWindowClass", L"Child Window", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 500, mw_hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (!cw_hwnd) { cout << "Creation of Main Window Failed" << endl; return -1; }


    ShowWindow(mw_hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(mw_hwnd);

    ShowWindow(cw_hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(cw_hwnd);
    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessageW(&msg, mw_hwnd, NULL, NULL)>0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}


LRESULT CALLBACK WNDProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        cout << "Main Window Created." << endl;
        break;
    }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wparam, lparam);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK ChWNDProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        cout << "Child Window Created." << endl;
        CreateWindowExW(NULL, L"Edit", L"Text Box 1", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|ES_MULTILINE, 200, 200, 100, 20, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        break;
    }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wparam, lparam);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: The `"ChildWindowClass"` isn't necessary. But now that it's there, it will need to have the `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` [extended window style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) set.

Comment: Did you set the style for the `cw_hwnd` window? Probably also need it on the `mw_hwnd` window. I still don't understand why `cw_hwnd` is there at all.

Comment: Yes, I set it for cw_hwnd and mw_hwnd. the cw_hwnd is here for representing my Idea only, the actual code is more complex and I have a class for the main window and a class for the child window and i have more than one child window , the actual program is a simulation program with main window , graphics child window , toolbar window and properties window. so if I used the actual code I don't think my idea will be clear at all

Comment: Have you considered using dialog? [create a modal dialog box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes)

Comment: I don't think dialogbox will be very effective in this case

Comment: If you want to keep the title bar, using Dialog is the only way.